# Error in y.predict.trend + y.predict.complement : non-conformable arrays

Tags: machine-learning, r, data-mining, predictive-modeling

I was using Dicekrigging in order to Bayesian optimization in R.

While finding the acquisition function I got the specified error. I got stuck for many hours. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
#install packages
library(DiceKrigging)
library(DiceOptim)
library(lhs)

nsteps <- 10

d=6

lower <- c(-2,-2,-2,0,0,0)

upper <- c(5,5,5,1,10,10)
X=lhs(n,d)

colnames(X)=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x4","x5","x6")

Temp=c(1:n)


mf2 <- km(~ 1+x1+sin(x2) +x3+I(x4^-1)+x5+x6,  design = X, 
response=Temp,covtype="matern5_2",
          nugget=epsilon,multistart = 5,control=list(maxit=500,trace=T,popsize=50))


model <- mf2

f1 <- function(X) {  x1 <- x[1]
x2 <- x[2]
x3 <- x[3]
x4 <- x[4]
x5 <- x[5]
x6 <- x[6]

L=-111.563*x1-29.81*sin(x2)+35.202*x3-.00012485/x4-1.045997*x5+11.6344*x6+13.1035
return(L)
}



oEGO <- EGO.nsteps(model = mf2, fun = f1, nsteps = nsteps,
                       + lower, upper, control = list(pop.size = 20, BFGSburnin = 2))


----------
```

When I run the last code it is showing:
Error in y.predict.trend + y.predict.complement : non-conformable arrays

Comment: There are many issues in the code, i'm working on that. will give you the code but need some help. what is that lhs(throwing an error), what is n value?, what is the outcome you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the code, have a look:

```
#install packages
library(DiceKriging)
library(DiceOptim)
library(lhs)

nsteps <- 10
n <- 10
d <- 6
lower <- c(-2,-2,-2,0,0,0)
upper <- c(5,5,5,1,10,10)
x <- randomLHS(n,d)

colnames(x)=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6")

Temp=c(1:n)


mf2 <- km(~ 1+x1+sin(x2)+x3+I(x4^-1)+x5+x6,  
          design = X, 
          response=Temp,
          covtype="matern5_2",
          nugget = NULL, nugget.estim=FALSE,
          multistart = 5,
          control=list(maxit=500,trace=T,popsize=50))

f1 <- function(x) {  
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  x3 <- x[3]
  x4 <- x[4]
  x5 <- x[5]
  x6 <- x[6]
  L=-111.563*x1-29.81*sin(x2)+35.202*x3-.00012485/x4-1.045997*x5+11.6344*x6+13.1035
  return(L)
}

oEGO <- EGO.nsteps(mf2,f1,nsteps,lower,upper)
```

you are getting some result but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Did this code help you? if yes, +1 is Appreciated